# Selecting Data Between Two Dates For Manually Inserted Dates

Tags: php, mysql, date

```
            SELECT * FROM users 
            WHERE birthday BETWEEN '08-06' AND  '15-06'
```

This is my query to select data between two dates. I know this is duplicate question but their is slight problem to my situation.

**The Dates which I m storing are manually inserted to db using dropdown list which is varchar datatype**

Problem: The Results for this query only selects data using date(dd) values and not compares whole date string

This is the result i m getting which selects data from month 7 as well

```
    bday
   09-06-1985
   08-06-1990
   09-07-1991
```

Comment: Do not store dates as varchar. Store them as dates otherwise they will not behave as such, including comparison operations.

Comment: But users selects dates through dropdown list @JanKaltoun

Comment: You need to sanitize the inputs and convert/save them as dates.

Comment: So their is no solution for such problem ? @JanKaltoun

Comment: you need to rethink this completely. MySQL has built-in features for this and you're working too hard. If you're not too far into this, consider using those and the user input methods. Querying with varchar makes it much harder

Comment: yes I just completely changed my database date system @Fred-ii- and thank you everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like other people write in comments, it's always best to use datetime data type for date. You can compare your varchar date like this

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(birthday, '%d-%m')
  BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('08-06', '%d-%m')
    AND STR_TO_DATE('15-06', '%d-%m')
```

Comment: Okay Thankyou.But is it possible to store date using dd-mm-yyyy ?

Comment: @AbhishekBurkule yes,